# Difficulty with sliding div in usin jQuery

Tags: jquery, slidetoggle

I've looked at a bunch of different posts on here regarding this, I think I'm following everything correctly, but my code is not executing, so obviously I'm not. Wondering if someone here may notice something that I'm overlooking.

I have a navbar, and when users hovers on a menu item I want a div to slide down from under it and show a bunch of content.

Here's the markup:

```
<nav class="site-navigation main-navigation" role="navigation">
    <div class="menu-1-container">
        <ul id="menu-1" class="menu">
             <li id="menu-item-1">
                <a href="#">Releases</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</nav>

<div class="dropdown-contain">
    <p>Content</p>
</div>
```

Here's the css:

```
.dropdown-contain {
    display: none;
}
```

Here's the .js (Still learning, and haven't fully grasped):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".menu-item-475").hover(function () {
        $(".dropdown-contain").stop(true, true).slideToggle("slow");
    });
});
```

Here's a fiddle.
http://jsfiddle.net/ericbrockman/mk4yu/3/

thanks a bunch!!

Comment: First of all, include the jquery version you are using on the fiddle via top left dropdown

Comment: and second of all, if you click 'tidy up' in jsfiddle and your code is still messed up, it means your syntax is wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i have altered your fiddle a bit, have a look  [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/TheBanana/mk4yu/9/)

things to notice:

```
1 - you should select your jquery library on the left panel of jsfiddle.
2 - delegating event handlers by attaching them to document seem to work better for me
3 - using custom animation you have more control over the sliding
4 - set position:absolute for the sliding panel if you want it to work correctly
5 - when attaching the mouse hover to a menu item, always include the submenu as well or you will not be able to click the submenu since when you move the mouse out of the menu item the submenu goes off
```

if you have more questions, please let me know.
-if my answer helped you, please consider accepting it :)

Comment: Thanks @banana that's very helpful. Really appreciate the thoughtful response and the comments in the js (super useful for a newbie like me). This works well in the fiddle, but doesn't seem to be working on the live site for some reason. Here's the URL if you're interested in taking a look: http://ericbrockmanwebsites.com/

Comment: i had a look. it seems you have not included the jQuery libraries. if you look in developer console in your browser, you will notice an exception '$ is not a function' this is because jQuery is an extension library to javascript and it adds the jQuery $ selector to javascript. jQuery can be downloaded for free, just google 'download jQuery' its merely 1 .js file, link it to your page and it will work :)

Comment: Sorry, @Banana if you're looking at the site, the relevant link is actually #menu-item-475 (Releases) in the main nav on the top of the page.

Comment: hmmm, I have this in my head: <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

Comment: this one is commented out by the `<!--[if lt IE 9]>` section, move it outside

Comment: OMG That's so embarrassing. Thank you! Answer accepted. Appreciate it!